# VS2017 encapsulate only with getter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio you can use refactoring to automatically encapsulate a field:

```
protected bool grounded
```

becomes

```
private bool grounded;

protected bool Grounded
{
    get
    {
        return grounded;
    }
    set
    {
        grounded = value;
    }
}
```

Which is very handy, but most of the time I only want to generate the getter and not the getter and the setter, is there an option to do that?

I can't seem to find it anywhere, so I have to erase the setter every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your implementation is the default one you can instead use the auto-property and write:

```
public bool Grounded { get; set; }
```

and then with the setter:

```
public bool Grounded { get; }
// or
public bool Grounded { get; private set; }
```

It basically compiles to what you wrote.
In VS you have a macro: write `prop` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and it will generate the line above

Comment: oh yea I can do "public bool Grounded { get; private set; }" that's perfect